# How to Commit files by creating a memory index in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

Create your own memory index and use it instead of the index of the repository.
but I can't initialize it.the error message is `could not initialize index entry, Index is not backed up by an existing repository`,do something like this:

```
...
git_repository_open(&repo, ...); // same as before
git_index_new(&index); // create in-memory index
git_revparse_single(headTree, repo, "HEAD^{tree}");  // get head Tree
git_index_read_tree(index, headTree); // initialize to the current HEAD
git_index_add_by_path(index, "1.txt"); //update the nominated file(s).but it not work 
git_index_write_tree_to(&oid, index, repo); // write the tree into the repo
git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &oid); // same as before
...
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246887/create-a-tree-object-from-a-temporary-index-using-libgit2-git2go?

Comment: It’s a meaning with his reply, but I can’t implement it, I don’t know where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Your in-memory index is not bound to a repository.  Therefore you can’t do things that implicitly touch the working directory - because that’s a concept tied to a repository object and there isn’t one for your index.

Thus `git_index_add_by_path` will fail when operating on an in-memory index.  It can’t find that path, it has no concept of where to look for it.

`git_index_add_by_path` works by reading the file on disk to create a `git_index_entry`.  It’s a convenience function.

Instead, you can use `git_index_add` with the index entry data.

Comment: @Thomson,Thank your very much, the new add file can be successfully committed when use git_index_add, but the modified file cannot be commit.because, It can't be written to disk when use git_index_write. then,I use git_index_add to add entry, and use git_index_add_bypath,and use git_index_write to write the dask, it also failde.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand why you want an in-memory index?  Everything you've described makes it sound like you want to get the repository's index directly with `git_repository_index(&index, repo)`?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean, could you explain that in more detail, maybe in your question itself?  In any case, if you want to write the index to disk, then it _is_ the repository's index by definition.

Comment: 1.git add 1.txt 2.txt (libgit2 use git_index_add_bypath, git_index_write). 
2.git delete 3.txt(libgit2 use git_index_remove_bypath, git_index_write).
3.git commit 1.txt -m "Initial commit with 1.txt"(just commit '1.txt').
However, The 2.txt, 3.txt status is also changes when I use git_index_repository(&index, repo), So, I want to use in-memroy index to completed it.

Comment: @eThomson, 1."git commit -a" submits all the changes in the repository. 2. "git commit 1.txt, 2.txt". Only submit the files in the list (1.txt, 2.txt), I just want to implement the second commit command in libgit2.

Comment: @JonseJonse It's incredibly hard to read this - can you just write the git commands that you're trying to emulate in your question (so that it can be formatted readably)?  If you're trying to emulate git command line then you shouldn't need an in-memory index.

Comment: @eThomson,yes, I just want to implement the "git commit <file>" command (specify file submission) in libgit2. When I use the repository index, it can automatically stage the modified and deleted files. Is there a good way to specify file submissions in libgit2?